# Loading pages using ng-view does not work

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, ng-view, angularjs-1.6

I'm working on my first AngularJS Router using Brackets editor for me to test it on a localhost (I understand it will not work on my local machine). The include files works OK, but It will not load all 5 HTML files. Please see all of the codes on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/f09xYs24HThNT3Nfntp4?p=preview). I don't understand what's missing.

HTML

```
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<!-- header section -->
<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>

<br><br>

<!-- views section -->
<div ng-view>View pages here...</div>

<br><br>

<!-- footer section -->
<div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>

</body>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/1', {
    templateUrl: '1.html'
})
$routeProvider.when('/2', {
   templateUrl: '2.html'
})
$routeProvider.when('/3', {
    templateUrl: '3.html'
})
$routeProvider.when('/4', {
   templateUrl: '4.html'
})
$routeProvider.when('/5', {
    templateUrl: '5.html'
})
});
```

Comment: The question shows AngularJS V1.6 but the PLNKR use V1.2. Is this a V1.6 question or a V1.2 question? This is important because the default hashbang prefix has changed between the two versions.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `href="#/1"` to `href="#!1"`

```
<div>
    <a href="#!1">One</a>
    <a href="#!2">Two</a>
    <a href="#!3">Three</a>
    <a href="#!4">Four</a>
    <a href="#!5">Five</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, but Its weird. It works on <https://plnkr.co/edit/f09xYs24HThNT3Nfntp4?p=preview> without the `!`.

Comment: The default hash bang prefix was changed with V1.6. For more information see, [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-location-).

Comment: Yeah I was about to commen that out, In this first plunker you had 1.6.4 and now you changed to 1.2.3

Comment: Yeah, I changed it back it works on Plunker, but my actual project still showing blank page.